# Code is returning wrong value for factorials

Tags: java, factorial

My code for factorials works fine up until n=13 where it then starts giving me the wrong answer. Does anyone know why?

```
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(13));
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            n=n*i;
        }

        return n;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### `int` is finite

Your problem is the 32bit integer limit.

Java's `int` datatype represents a signed 32bit integer meaning it can store values from -2^31 to 2^31-1 (2 147 483 647)

13! is 6 227 020 800 which is higher than that so it doesn't fit in an `int`.

### `long` is bigger than `int` but still finite

In order to fix this, you can use `long` which represents a signed 64bit integer:

```java
public static long factorial(long n) {
       
    for(int i=(int)n-1;i>=1;i--){
        n=n*i;
 }
    return n;
}
```

`long` allows ranges from -2^63 up to 2^63-1 (a number with 18 digits) which allows factorials until `20!`.

### Get real big with `BigInteger`

If you want to. go even further, you can use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```java
public static BigInteger factorial(long n) {
    BigInteger value=BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    for(int i=n-1;i>=1;i--){
        value=value.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return value;
}
```

While `BigInteger` also isn't infinite (ranging from `-2^(2^32)` until to `-2^(2^32)` at minimum), it should be sufficient for your purpose. This is explained in [the Javadoc of `BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html):

> BigInteger must support values in the range -2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) to +2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive)